# Understanding Pitch Detection with Autocorrelation Methods

Tags: sampling, autocorrelation, pitch

I've been reading through [A Smarter Way to Find Pitch](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/tartini/papers/A_Smarter_Way_to_Find_Pitch.pdf), describing its pitch detection algorithm using autocorrelation.

I've been having trouble understanding the accuracy claims. It says:

> MPM runs in real time with a standard 44.1 kHz sampling rate. It operates without using low-pass filtering so
>   it can work on sound with high harmonic frequencies such
>   as a violin and it can display pitch changes of one cent reliably.

I cannot fathom how detecting changes of one cent is possible. Considering a note played at 441Hz, sampled at 44.1kHz, one would measure a first peak at tao=100 samples (delay space).

The next closest note which could be measured, by my understanding, would have a peak at the 101st sample. This would be a frequency of 437Hz, or about 16 cents lower than the first note. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

For higher resolution periodicity estimation, given properly band-limited data, the data can be upsampled (interpolated) before autocorrelation, and/or, the autocorrelation results can be interpolated (Sinc kernel or some order of polynomial).

This, of course, assumes the signal has a high enough S/N, and that the periodicity itself is unmodulated in timbre(harmonic content), phase, frequency, or amplitude, which isn’t always true of real-world pitched sounds.  Thus a larger number of periods may be needed for a some desired statistical error bound on the pitch estimation.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I'm still unclear on whether or not this is what the researchers intended, however. They explicitly describe calculating the pitch, making no mention of those methods:
`The pitch period is equal to the delay, τ, at the chosen key maximum. The corresponding frequency is obtained by dividing the sample rate by the pitch period (in samples).`
In which case I am still confused as to where the aforementioned accuracy would come from.

Answer (score 1):

to add to hot's answer, when using autocorrelation or [an equivalent method like AMDF or ASDF](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29962/how-to-deal-with-low-fundamental-when-using-amdf-for-pitch-extraction/29968#29968), although the autocorrelation $R_x[k]$ is evaluated **only** at integer values of lag $k$, which means the peak value and initial period length will be an integer number of samples, you can use [quadratic interpolation using the point at the peak and the two neighboring values, to get the location of the *"true"* peak](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19961/pitch-extraction-for-speech/19987#19987).  That will give you a **precision** (not the same as "accuracy") of better than an integer number of samples lag.

take a look at those two other linked answers to get a sorta formal mathematical expression of the problem and how i approached solving it.