# How to find the Pitch of a utterance using narrowband spectrogram

Tags: spectrogram, pitch

Can anyone tell me how to find the pitch of an utterance from it's narrow band spectrogram? I am pretty new to the speech processing domain so any help is appreciated. 
P.S. I need methods to estimate the pitch from the narrow band spectrogram only. Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

[image: Here is the narrow band spectrogram that I have obtained.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pitch extraction for speech](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19961/pitch-extraction-for-speech)

Comment: (in essence: your spectrogram is nice, but it's probably easier to calculate your own pitch measure from the raw data)

Comment: Actually it is part of an assignment and we have to estimate the pitch from the narrow band spectrogram only. If you could please provide me any help in this regard

Comment: so, what are the parameters of that spectrogram?